# Given N number display M*M format

Tags: java, algorithm

We giving a number (n) the first line 
Program output: The next  lines contain  space-separated integers, describing the first arrangement.

`n=m^2`
For example: 9

```
Output:1  2  3
       4  5  6
       7  8  9
```

For example: 16

Output:
[image: asa]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int m;
        System.out.println("Enter number of team");
        n = scanner.nextInt();

        m = (int) Math.sqrt(n);

        int[][] array = new int[m][m];


        for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                array[i][j]=j+1;
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

> Buy my program output
>
> Entry: 3
>
> Output:
>
> 123
>
> 123
>
> 123

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: So what is your question, specifically?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This smells like a Leetcode/Hackerrank problem...

Comment: Why your question is not quite good: it is unclear what you are asking. Your question does not contain a question. There's a code sample which looks more or less fine. What is your difficulty?

Comment: We are giving a number: (N): 16
M^2=N; M=4
So, Program output row:4 column:4
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: But you still haven't asked a question.  All you've done is pasted a problem statement and pasted some code.  We have no idea how to help you.

Comment: @JoeC please see again the post

Comment: I see not a single question mark in your post.. What is your question? Are you stuck on something? Does the program not produce the desired output? All you're done is give requirements and code.

Comment: @GBlodgett  please see again the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still haven't asked any question, but I assume that your program gives wrong answer (as it really do) and you don't know why.
For example: for n=16 it prints:

```
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

The following code fragment is responsible:

```
array[i][j]=j+1;
System.out.print(array[i][j]);
```

Firstly, you don't print spaces, so numbers aren't separated. Secondly, you have to use another formula: `i*m+j+1` (as number depends on both `i` and `j`). Also, there is no point in keeping array, but it's not an error.

Suggested correction:

```
System.out.print(m*i+j+1 + " ");
```

Comment: Correct output:
1 2 3 4-5 6 7 8-9 10 11 12-13 14 15 16